# How to fire the required attribute of html5 textbox on click of anchor tag

Tags: html

I have the following html5 code snippet with anchor tag and two textbox:

```
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" required /><br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" required /><br />
<a class="test" href="#" onclick="CheckData();">CheckData</a>
```

If I replace the anchor tag with the following tag :

```
<input text="Test" type="Submit"/>
```

then the html5 required attribute is firing and showing the validation for both the text boxes.

Can anyone help me out how to fire the required field attribute of text box on click of the anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you trigger the validation message popover manually, only through form submission. You can check the validity via the constraint validation API with element.checkValidity(), but that validation doesn't trigger the popover message.